# Is 「~していれば」a conditional verb form?

Tags: meaning, conditionals

I'm wondering if 「~していれば」is not only a conditional verb form.

Because I once encountered a sentence; 「別担当者であれば...」.

I thought this sentence means "If there is a different person-in-charge...".

However, I learned that it means "There is a different person-in-charge..."

So, for the sentence 「１か月の出勤日数が何日出勤していれば交通費が出るのですか。」、I'm not sure if my understanding is correct that it means "If I go work for a certain number of days within a month, would I receive a fee for that number of days I went to work?".

Can anyone please explain the definition of 「~していれば」?

Comment: its hard to imagine that 別担当者であれば means "there is a different person-in-charge" and not "if there is a different person-in-charge" without seeing the entire context.

Comment: and the second sentence, １か月の出勤日数が何日出勤していれば交通費が出るのですか doesn't seem to make grammatical sense to me. where did you get the sentence from? していれば has normally the same meaning as any conditional form verb, just simply with the ている form. I'm inclined to think both your example sentence and your understanding of the 別担当者であれあば clause are both a little faulty.

Comment: Can't think of a situation where 「していれば」 is not conditional or hypothetical.

Answer (score 0):

Combination of interrogative words and conditional clauses can translate in English to "what/how .... should ...?". e.g どうすればいい : What should I do?

１か月の出勤日数が何日出勤していれば交通費が出るのですか means "How many days per month do I need to attend (the work place) to receive transportation fee?".